# Affine Structure Resolution for the Vasicek model

Tags: finance-mathematics, short-rate, vasicek, ornstein-uhlenbeck

I would like to now how to solve the PDE of the affine structure under Vasicek.I am delineating the steps:

First let's posit the OU process under a Risk Neutral Measure such as :
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}r_t=\mu(t,r_t)\mathrm{d}t+\sigma(t,r_t)\mathrm{d}W_t
\end{align*}

Then comes the bond PDE:

\begin{align*}
P_t + \mu(t,r) P_r + \frac{1}{2}\sigma(t,r)^2P_{rr} -rP=0,
\end{align*}
We Write the penny zero coupon bond's formula and mixed it with the Original PDE,using a latent $r_t$ variable :

\begin{align*}
P(t,T)=e^{A(t,T)-r_tB(t,T)}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
P_t(t,T) &=\big(A_t(t,T)-r_tB_t(t,T)\big)\cdot P(t,T), \\
P_r(t,T) &= -B(t,T)\cdot P(t,T), \\
P_{rr}(t,T) &= B(t,T)^2\cdot P(t,T).
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
A_t(t,T) - \mu(t,r) B(t,T) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma(t,r)^2B(t,T)^2 +(-B_t(t,T)-1)r &=0.
\end{align*}

In the Vasicek case, $\mu(t,r_t)=\kappa(\theta-r_t)$ and $\sigma(t,r_t)=\sigma$.Afterward the calculations are straightforward:

\begin{align*}
A_t(t,T) - \kappa \theta B(t,T) + \kappa r B(t,T) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2B(t,T)^2 +(-B_t(t,T)-1)r &=0 \\
\implies A_t(t,T) - \kappa \theta B(t,T) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2B(t,T)^2-(1+B_t(t,T)-\kappa B(t,T))r &=0.
\end{align*}

And we end up with two equations such :

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
A_t(t,T) - \kappa \theta B(t,T) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2B(t,T)^2 &= 0, \\
1+B_t(t,T)-\kappa B(t,T) &= 0,\\
u.c :  A(T,T)=B(T,T)=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
However I don't understand the development we must do so as to find $B_t(t,T) = e^{-k(T-t)}$ and hence $B(t,T) = \frac{-1+e^{-k(T-t)}}{k}$.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We begin with the equation $1+B_t(t,T)-kB(t,T) = 0 \quad(1)$

\begin{align}
(1) & \iff e^{-kt}+e^{-kt}B_t(t,T)+(-k)e^{-kt}B(t,T) = 0 \\
& \iff e^{-kt}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(e^{-kt}B(t,T)\right) = 0 \\
& \iff \int_t^Te^{-ku}du+ \int_t^T\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(e^{-ku}B(t,T)\right)du = 0 \\
& \iff \int_t^Te^{-ku}du+ \int_t^T\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(e^{-ku}B(t,T)\right)du = 0 \\ 
& \iff\frac{e^{-kt}-e^{-kT}}{k} +\left(e^{-kT}B(T,T) - e^{-kt}B(t,T)\right) = 0 \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
From $(2)$, you can deduce the closed form expression of $B(t,T)$.

Answer (score -1):

there's a great chapter going over this entire derivation in "Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-Time Models" by Shreve. Let me know if you cant download it. It's how I learned this confusing ass stochastic calc stuff :)

Comment: Welcome to Quant.SE! :) Shreve's book is certainly great and covers short rate models. Your current answer is more of a comment. Perhaps you'd like to elaborate a bit on the details you've read in Shreve's book?

Comment: @Kevin Sorry don't have time to elaborate. But Chapter 10 of that book goes over the complete derivation

Comment: I checked and didn’t find

Comment: @lays Chapter 6.5: Interest Rate Models. Page 272